# pre-receive hook declined error while pushing bare repo to gitlab with maintainer role

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I cloned my existing repo with the following command :

```
git clone --bare http://ourstashrepo/ourrepo.git
```

I created a project under my gitlab repo and used the gitlab clone url to push with the following commands (My role is maintainer):

```
cd ourrepo.git
git push --mirror <gitlaburl>
```

I am getting the following error for every branch including master:

```
! [remote rejected]     release/1.9 -> release/1.9 (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I removed protected for master branch in project > Settings > Repository > "Protected branches",  as suggested in some questions related to this. but none of them worked.

How can I resolve this issue?